# Version in requirements.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to know how to use place holders in requirements.yaml file for versions field or if there is a way to Implementation Automatic dependencies version

dependencies:
- name: nuclei-wallet-async
  version: {{ .Values.version_dep }}
  repository: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts

Declared the version_dep in values.yaml file but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no support to parameterize requirements.yaml. Also refer to the [official helm documentation for requirement files](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/#requirements-files). It makes no sense as you cant guarentee the helm package functionality if somebody puts random version numbers into the chart dependencies.

An option would be to use [conditions](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/#conditions-and-tags).

For example you could introduce values to be evaluated by a condition in requirements.yaml.

```
# requirements.yaml
dependencies:
      - name: subchart1
        repository: http://localhost:10191
        version: 0.1.0
        condition: subchartversion1.enabled
      - name: subchart1
        repository: http://localhost:10191
        version: 0.2.0
        condition: subchartversion2.enabled
```

But that would be only a workaround and no best practice.